Why everyone talks SOR and nobody JOR?
Context
I am considering both Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel to be well-established. Essentially, given a relaxation parameter $\omega$, we have the following two methods (we will indicate the result of Jacobi over $x$ with $x_J$ and similarly for GS).
$$
\text{(JOR)} \qquad x^{(k)} = (1-\alpha)x^{(k-1)} + \alpha x_J^{(k-1)}
$$
$$
\text{(SOR)} \qquad x^{(k)} = (1-\alpha)x^{(k-1)} + \alpha x_{GS}^{(k-1)}
$$
Question
In (almost) every single book I have checked, only SOR is given, and online there is very little literature about JOR. Given that Jacobi has the advantage of bein parallelizable over GS (even though half as fast for tridiagonal matrices), and supporting that this benefit is translated to JOR and SOR, why is JOR so much less important?

Your question appears to be based on the premise that $SOR$ cannot be parallelized. This is not the case.There are many parallel algorithms for solving triangular linear systems. Moreover, It is possible to argue that both methods have been incompatible with modern computer hardware since the mid-1990s. It is possible to expand upon these subjects, but I think that you should either edit your question or ask a new question. Consider the stack for scientific computing as an alternative forum for your question.
